# Execute Macro via USB device

Tags: usb, macros

I want to execute a macro via hardware, and not software. Ideally being OS-independent.

Here are some ideas that I've had and how far I got on each of them:

1. Pre-programmed Mouse. Since the macro will mainly move the mouse I looked for a mouse that I could pre-programmed the movements into, but everything I found required some software.
2. USBThumb. I'm not completely sure what this is as whenever I look into it all I find are USB thumb drives. Though I found the term [on instructables.com](https://www.instructables.com/The-Trickster-USB-Computer-Prank/) while looking at if I could repurpose the trickster device they talk about for my usecase, though all of the links they have that provide vital information to following the article does not show anything, instead I get a blank screen.
3. Programmable USB Peripheral. I tried searching for a USB Peripheral that I could program myself, though I didn't find anything.
4. Creating a USB device. I have researched this topic before and I believe I understand the basics, though not enough to actually create a USB device... much less being able to program move movements into it.

With that being said: What would the best way to do this? Is there a way to do it other than creating a USB device from scratch? And If creating a USB device from scratch is the only way, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What kind of macro? Does it have to ensure the device being controlled (laptop?) is currently on?

Comment: @Ram I mainly just want to be able to move the cursor in predefined patterns, as for the device wouldn't it have to be on? I don't see how it would work if the device is off

Comment: It would have to be on to work but perhaps it needs to be aware of error states (I can't execute the macro to disable the electric fence, flash an alarm indicating that I can't disable the electric fence so Cyber doesn't assume it worked).

Comment: If you just want to move the mouse around you could in all likelihood do this using software. If not then I expect you will need to either hack a mouse or emulate one.

Comment: If you had to choose one, would you choose to hack a mouse, or emulate one? Also, are you able to point me in the right direction for researching it?

Comment: It depends on my actual need - you are keeping it abstract presumably to pout your reason for going h/w out of scope but without the actual application IDK what I would ultimately do.